# Simple reference frame question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

Suppose a train is moving at some constant velocity $V$ with a bed sitting still on top. When the train decelerates at some rate $-A$ then the bed will move at some acceleration $A$. I can't seem to get an intuition for how this comes to be. I have looked online and find no help.

Comment: "the bed will move ..." in which reference frame? Is there friction between the bed and the train?

Comment: The bed falls off the train @Bill N I guess there's no friction

Comment: The bed also decelerates at -A. If the train and the bed have different accelerations, the bed's occupant is going to have a very rude awakening when the bed slams into a wall.

Comment: Do you wear a seatbelt?

Comment: If there is no friction the bed keeps moving at V relative to the ground until it hits the front of the train (or wagon)

Answer (score 1):

You need to think in terms of what happens in WHICH reference frame.

In the frame of the train, the bed will indeed move forward with acceleration A. Maybe it will help your intuition, if you think about what you feel on a car, when it brakes . You feel pushed forward. Same is the case with the bed.

But in the frame of the ground , when the train decelerates at -A , the bed keeps going forward at velocity v ( since you have assumed there is no friction, hence there is nothing to slow down the bed, even though the train is slowing down )

Answer (score 0):

The bed acceleration $A$ would be that perceived by an observer in the non-inertial train frame. To someone standing on the ground next to the track, the bed has no acceleration, until it slides off and is subject to gravity, because no net force is acting on the bed (in the case of no friction).